# Chrome Extension, message passing when This site can’t be reached

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a created a Google Chrome extension. In my background.js script, I listen for page changes and send either chrome.tabs or chrome.runtime send message when the page has loaded (i.e. `changeInfo.status === complete`). For most web pages, I am able to receive `chrome.tabs.sendMessages` in content scripts without any issues, however, I have just come across an instance where the webpage couldn't be loaded :`This site can’t be reached` (`changeInfo.status` still returns as `complete`)

As a result, my content script does not receive any message. My extension relies on this message to continue running. Is there a way to establish whether the page has not loaded properly as some form of property in changeInfo or tab perhaps?

Here is my listener in `background.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

        tabid = tab;


if (status === "ready")
        {
           if (tab.url !== undefined && changeInfo.status == "complete") {

           status = "processing";

                if (stop === false){  

                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id,{type:"website found", currentURL:currentURL,id: basicData.id, info:basicData});}

                  }
              }

      else if (status === "getBasic")
      {

            if (tab.url !== undefined && changeInfo.status == "complete") {
              if (stop === false){

        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"triggerNext"})}
            }
      }

    });
```

All help is appreciated  and I am open to all solutions.

Comment: The error should be reported in [chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onErrorOccurred).

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener((object, details)=>{
console.log(object);
console.log(details);

  }) into background.js but I get the following error: Cannot read property 'onErrorOccurred' of undefined

Comment: The error message says that chrome.webNavigation is undefined, which means you didn't add the necessary permission `"webNavigation"` in manifest.json: https://puu.sh/Ezbg6/d32ac6aa76.png

Comment: I have stumbled across another issue as a result. I wish to navigate away from this broken page, but since I have do not have access to content script message listeners whilst the page is broken, I am not sure how to do this. Is there a way to navigate away from the page using background.js or popup.js?

Comment: chrome.tabs.update( tab.id, { url: "http:/google.co.uk" } ); this works in background.js for anyone else wondering the same thing.